# Ext.GridPanel rendered with width of 10001px

Tags: css, extjs, gridpanel

I have a Ext.grid.GridPanel and it is rendered into my Page with a width of 10001px. (Tested in FireFox Chrome and IE). Always the same.

The Gridpanel is rendered into a `<table><td>` element so that i can layout it together with other element. (There's no way to ommit the tables. If i could i wouldn't use them).

The div element which encapsulates the table is 1614px of width so how can this happen?

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using, when are you adding the grid, do you have code samples or a live test we can use to analyse?

Comment: Good question! I'm currently working on a pretty old project. I just found out the version is: Ext JS Library 2.2.1. I will do an update first.

Comment: @ChrisR The simple Update solved the problem. Would you mind posting this as an answer? Or should i do?

Comment: go ahead and post your answer :) I merely suggested updating if you aren't on the latest version. didn't know it would solve it in one go :)

Comment: Can you post your code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from Version 2.2.1 to Version 3.3.1 solved my Problem. If someone else is experiencing the same problem and has to update to version 3. You should really use this forum post here to upgrade:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?70352-Upgrading-to-Ext-3

there are a few critical changes which could break your application.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?15642-2.0b1-SOLVED-Grid-autoWidth-renders-grid-10x-width-of-screen-in-IE6) on the ExtJs forum site. The solution is stated there (Just create a Viewport with layout:'fit' and add the Grid to it.)

Comment: Thanks! I already found that one on the web and tried it, but this doesn't solve it. I think this one is really related to an IE problem, but i have this in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Grid has to be rendered to either A) an explicitly-sized element or B) an Ext Container that manages layout. The reference to adding the grid to a viewport from TurBas' answer relates to option B. In your case, you'll have to give your TD a fixed size for this to work.  This begs the question... why are you rendering the grid into a table?

Comment: It has to be rendered to a table because of the surrounding plattform which is a pretty old but "mature" product which layouts every component through tables.